# configmaps "aws-auth" not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I launched an EKS cluster using terraform [module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest)

My template looks something like this:

```
module "eks" {
source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
version         = "17.20.0"
cluster_name    = "${var.cluster_name}"
cluster_version = var.cluster_version
subnets         = ["${var.public_subnet_1}", 
"${var.public_subnet_2}","${var.public_subnet_3}"]
vpc_id          = var.vpc_id
cluster_security_group_id = "${var.master_sg_id}"
worker_security_group_id =  "${var.master_sg_id}"
workers_additional_policies =[aws_iam_policy.siera_alb_ingress_controller_policy.arn]
workers_role_name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.environment}-${var.aws_region}-worker-role"
map_roles = [
  {
  rolearn   = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_no}:role/${var.cluster_name}-${var.environment}-${var.aws_region}-worker-role"
  username  = "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
  groups    = ["system:bootstrappers","system:nodes"]
  },
  {
  rolearn   = "arn:aws:sts::${var.account_no}:assumed-role/${var.assumed_role_1}"
  username  = "admin"
  groups    = ["system:masters","system:nodes","system:bootstrappers"]
  },
  {
  rolearn  = "arn:aws:sts::${var.account_no}:assumed-role/${var.assumed_role_2}"
  username  = "admin"
  groups    = ["system:masters","system:nodes","system:bootstrappers"]
  }
]
  tags = {
    Purpose = "${var.project}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }

worker_groups_launch_template = [
{
  name                  = "${var.cluster_name}-lt"
  key_name              = "${var.node_key}"
  additional_userdata   = <<EOT
                          "echo dummy" 
                          EOT
  instance_type         = "${var.node_size}"
  asg_min_size          = 3
  asg_desired_capacity  = 3
  asg_max_size          = 5
  autoscaling_enabled   = true
  asg_force_delete      = true
  public_ip             = true
  enable_monitoring     = false
  root_volume_size      = 80
  suspended_processes   = ["AZRebalance"]
  tags = [
    {
      "key"                 = "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled"
      "propagate_at_launch" = "false"
      "value"               = "true"
    },
    {
      "key"                 = "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/${var.cluster_name}"
      "propagate_at_launch" = "false"
      "value"               = "true"
    }
  ]
}
] 
manage_aws_auth = false 
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to add aws-auth configmap using map_roles.

After launching the cluster when I run `kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth`

It gives this error: `Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "aws-auth" not found`

What am I missing? Please help

Comment: Without knowing how you obtained the KUBECONFIG used to issue that `kubectl`, no one can help you, but almost always when EKS and kubectl fight, it's because the `exec:` in that kubectl isn't operating as the "owner IAM Role" of the EKS cluster

Comment: @mdaniel I updated the context using the eks cli `update-kubeconfig` command. If that's what you're asking

Comment: It won't be created automatically. You have to build the aws-auth YAML config and apply it manually for the first time.

Comment: You have explicitly set `manage_aws_auth = false` but it needs to be true for `map_roles`

Comment: @jordanm you are correct. Thanks It cleared the error. I'm getting this 'Error: configmaps "aws-auth" already exists' issue now. Any idea?

Comment: Did you see some of suggestions provided in [this issue](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/852)?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I scrapped this method cos it seemed buggy. I solved it using a kubectl provider `gavinbunney/kubectl`. Check it out. Worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 4):

Terraform needs to connect the the created cluster and use the cluster credentials to create the `aws-auth` configmap. Add this to the file that is creating the EKS cluster.

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "default" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "default" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.default.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.default.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
}
```

From HashiCorp [github repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/blob/main/_examples/eks/kubernetes-config/main.tf)

Comment: Crazy as it is, this solves the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hey im seeing the same issue and the problem is that kubernetes provider is not connecting to the recently created cluster. I have added a piece of code in the main.tf that made it before creating the module itself.

```
...
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.app_cluster.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.app_cluster.cluster_certificate_authority_data)

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    command     = "aws"
    # This requires the awscli to be installed locally where Terraform is executed
    args = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.app_cluster.cluster_id]
  }
}

module "app_cluster" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.0"

  cluster_name    = "${terraform.workspace}-cluster"
  cluster_version = "1.21"
  vpc_id     = "${var.vpc}"
  subnet_ids = "${var.subnets}"
  ...
```

Hope it helps!